# PHP TCPDF Undefined variable: l

Tags: php, tcpdf

Using a fresh install of TCPDF,
and a first run of example 1 @ http://www.tcpdf.org/examples.php
I'm getting "**Undefined variable: l**"

Thoughts?

Comment: Could you posted the full error message? Line number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably this line:

```
//set some language-dependent strings
$pdf->setLanguageArray($l);
```

They expect you to populate it with some sort of language array first.
Docs for that method: http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/classTCPDF.html#a2a7cc18749cac51d0efca5d491d9217c